# Local DB using cordova in 2020 [Android/IOS]

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I need to store objects and arrays in my cordova mobile app.

I need both android and ios support.

WebSQL seemed pretty good, but now it's not supported since september 2019 (version 13) on IOS, and I don't want to have different technology for android and ios.

IndexedDB is looking good, and is supported according to caniuse.com, but on the cordova docs, it's said it's not supported by IOS.

Cordova docs seems pretty old.

I work with Cordova and AngularJS, and I need to sync from time to time the local DB to Firebase.

Maybe someone can share his experience about local storage here.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in the RAM within an Object dynamically, you can store it with sqlite like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage

or you can store values in a file.
I give you a hint. You should do Android apps with java and IOS apps with swift. These are
natively supported programming languages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and about the rest : I'm not developping a fancy app. My app is like a website so I think cordova is easier since I know a bit of web developpement. I'm sure that developping in java or swift is better for heavy app, but in my case, I'm going to stick to simple things.